# Cannot remove headers-first XPATH in Selenium

Tags: python, excel, selenium, loops, xlsxwriter

I require your assistance with this issue below.

My code;

```
def rows_to_sheet():
    line = 1
    for i in data:
        browser.get(i)
        trs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr")
        for n, tr in enumerate(trs):
            row=[td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
            worksheet.write_row("A{}".format(line), row)
            line += 1
```

tr[1] contains headers. It is being written to excel.xlsx in a separate function.

```
/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td
```

And data I want to write to excel go through tr[2], tr[3], tr[4].. based on the search keyword like this;

```
/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td
/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td
/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[4]/td
/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[5]/td
```

However, tr[1] (header) is also written to excel.xlsx each time since I could not remove "tr[1]" from code block.

Could anyone help me on how to avoid/remove "tr[1]" iteration from my code please?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `if n == 1: continue` at the beginning of the inner loop?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check and let you know.